# Marquee/blinking header text for a screen in module pool program

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a module pool screen wherein the screen header text needs to be animated(marquee/blink). What could be the best possible solution to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean the text you display with SET TITLEBAR? If yes, I don't think there is any option to change anything, not even the color.

Comment: It's not just title bar text but one can consider any text that is to be displayed on module pool screen.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I see that this can be done is to put an HTML viewer inside a custom container on your ABAP dynpro screen and then pass the marquee/blink text as HTML to the viewer.
Demo program RSDEMO_HTML_VIEWER might be helpful in this regard.